# How do I calculate the gain of opamps in this circuit?

Tags: operational-amplifier, gain

I can calculate the gain of AD8656 but can not calculate the overall output gain of this circuit. What is the method of doing the calculation?

[image: circuit]

Comment: U3/U4 is set by Rg so read the datasheet. U5 is a noninverting amp (at DC) so look up that equation.

Comment: The whole circuit consists of 1st and second-order lowpass filter stages.

Comment: My bad, U5 is not a noninverting amp.

Comment: I think it rather is a classical unity gain Sallen-Key filter structure,

Answer (score 0):

The DC gain of the instrumentation amplifiers for differential inputs is determined by internal resistors plus Rg. It is a classic 3-op-amp instrumentation amplifier topology. The nominal gain equation is provided in the datasheet. DC gain of the AD8656 stages is +1.

The AD8656 stages form 2nd order low pass filters, and there is single pole low pass filtering on the inputs of the instrumentation amplifier.

Ideally the common mode gain is zero, but it will be affected by the  instrumentation amplifier CMRR at DC and by the matching of the RC networks at the inputs for AC signals.